# Knowing which Monitor is owned by Thread

Tags: java

How can I know which Monitor a Thread is owning ?
I've referred https://stackoverflow.com/a/17208717/6304546 , but I want the other way round.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java forced thread dump programmatically - like "jstack -F -l <PID>"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744850/java-forced-thread-dump-programmatically-like-jstack-f-l-pid)

Comment: `but I want the other way round` - what's your use case and requirements?